# How can I reference a function defined in another iPython notebook cell, within the same notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Suppose I've made a notebook in Jupyter, containing several different cells.

In the first cell, I define a self-contained Python module, with a number of useful functions.

In the second cell, I would like to write a program that uses the module defined in the first cell.

However, since the first cell does not have a file name, it's not clear to me how I should go about doing this.

Perhaps it would it be more conventional to have a separate notebook for each module? In that case, how would I go about importing content from the other notebook?

Comment: Huh? Everything run in the same notebook is treated as if you were in the same interactive python interpreter session (you are). You should be able to call functions you defined in one cell from any other cell as long as you've run the cell where your definitions are. It is as if it were one big module. What do you mean that the first cell has a file name? Perhaps it's been a while since I've used a notebook...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This makes more sense, but doesn't seem to be well documented. Perhaps you could make this an answer?

Comment: Perhaps to be clearer (since someone voted to close), I'm asking how scope works between cells in a notebook. I couldn't find good information on this, and haven't tested it yet myself. I'm trying to determine the suitability of this using ipython notebooks for a specific task.

Comment: You can think of a Notebook merely as a soupe- up text-editor that lets you write code and run it cell-by-cell. But the "scope" (which is not really an appropriate use of the term) is the whole notebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep everything within the same Jupyter Notebook.
In this case, your first cell would be a `class` with a number of useful functions or `methods`. In the second cell, you could create an instance of this class and go about using these `methods`.

[This](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/) is a good tutorial to get started with Classes and Methods in Python.